# Wifi is disabled - new install

Tags: networking, lenovo, intel-wireless

I have recently started to dual boot ubuntu 17.04 with Windows 10. I am able to connect to my LAN via a wired connection, but wifi shows "disabled" even after checking "enable wifi."  I have posted the relevant information in the link below.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/24645496/

System: Lenovo Legion y520

Answer (score 1):

Wireless is blocked by the `ideapad_laptop` module. You can disable it by running

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf <<< "blacklist ideapad_laptop"
```

Reboot to apply.